# iPhone - Auto-lock greyed out

Tags: iphone

I have observed the Auto-Lock to become greyed out and unavailable while the battery saver mode is turned on and the iPhone is charging. However, it remains disabled on my iPhone despite turning off battery saver mode.

[image]

What's the reason for this behaviour and how do I enable the Auto-Lock?

Comment: No answer? Seriously?

Comment: Did you try restarting your iPhone?

Comment: Not helpful Nimesh.

Comment: If you are running iOS 11.x, try upgrading to iOS 11.4 (released a few hours ago). See if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Did you perform a "hard reset"? Or just turned off the iPhone and turned it on again? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201412, see "If your screen is black or frozen" to do hard reset